# How to make WordPress search.php display all strings found on pages or posts

Tags: php, search

What I want to achieve is that when I type for example "house" in the search field, I want my `search.php` to display all sentences where "house" is written with the link of the page.

Down here is my `search.php` template:

```
<section class="text-area arbeitg-1 container">

<h1><?php _e('Search Results for:'); echo ' ' . get_search_query(); ?></h1>

<h2><?php _e('Search Results:'); ?></h2>

<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="search-block">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <p>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read More'); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h3><?php _e('No results for: '); echo get_search_query(); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is rather unclear what you're asking. Please edit your post to clearly state (1) what you're trying to achieve, (2) what you've tried yourself, and (3) what did and didn't work in your approach.

Comment: Can you check it now, it's more clear I think.

Comment: Thanks. What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: 2 days I'm searching for the answer, I made this search.php according to codex, and with help of Relevanssi plugin, but that's not what I'm searching for, I am still getting same results. Ofc I was playing with this code but none of them was good.